# How to create a generic array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
class car<T>{ 
    car<T>[] name;
    name=(car<T>[]) new Object[5];

}
```

I tried to create an array of the class but the declare seem wrong. how should I set length of the array to 5 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.reflect.Array#newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...)):

```java
car<T>[] name = (car<T>[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(car.class, 5);
```